# Object Collection Distance to Point Shaders and Curve Sample Shader

Tags: geometry-nodes, shader-nodes

Given any object it is relatively easy to create an influence point to drive a gradient / a procedural sphere color in an object:
[image]

### Point(Object position) Collection

How would one go about converting this setup to extend the same features to a collection of N amount of objects that can all modify this object color?

*I imagine capturing the positions and scales of each object and somehow passing them to the shader nodes.*
[image]

### Curve Collection

And how would you further go about extending this property to:

- A) work with a single curve and sample all points on that curve to draw the shape of that curve and its control-point radius:
- B) work with a collection of curves

**What I Have / Can Do:**
[image]
**What I need** (photoshopped):
[image]

**Extra:** if each object could have an attribute that drives the falloff (color ramp) that would be incredible.

#### THANK YOU !!!

Blender 4.0 Blend File:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/17YN2f9Sg0zbx0T8isy7f23F76I0r03CD/view?usp=sharing

Points:
https://www.youtube.com/embed/mL407HL4FvQ?si=-i9BLaJSF9vc1Tk8

Curves:
https://www.youtube.com/embed/IAeO3L5u28w?si=963nqLHGNJo3R9cy